# How to get arrays from a single javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to extract data of similar item from a large object and save this data as arrays of these similar items.

Here is the object(`moreProductInfo1`):

```
{
    "SKU1": "1",
    "productId1": "2",
    "condition1": "Refurbrished",
    "price1": "3",
    "quantity1": "4",
    "colorMap1": "5",
    "SKU2": "11",
    "SKU3": "111",
    "productId2": "22",
    "productId3": "222",
    "condition2": "Old",
    "condition3": "Used",
    "price2": "33",
    "price3": "333",
    "quantity2": "44",
    "quantity3": "444",
    "colorMap2": "55",
    "colorMap3": "555"
}
```

I would like to end up with:

```
[{
    "SKU": "1",
    "productId": "2",
    "condition": "Refurbrished",
    "price": "3",
    "quantity": "4",
    "colorMap": "5",
},
{
    "SKU": "11",
    "productId": "22",
    "condition": "Old",
    "price": "33",
    "quantity": "44",
    "colorMap": "55",
},
{
    "SKU": "111",
    "productId": "222",
    "condition": "Used",
    "price": "333",
    "quantity": "444",
    "colorMap": "555"
}]
```

I have tried the following to iterate through the object and seperate it out based on the key:

```
...
const [productsArray, setProductsArray] = useState([]);

...

addedVariation.map((curr, idx, arr) => {

  for (var key of Object?.keys(moreProductInfo1)) {

    if (key?.includes(`${idx + 1}`)) {
      setProductsArray([
        ...productsArray,
        {
          attribute: Object?.keys(curr)?.[idx],
          attributeValue: Object?.values(curr)?.[idx],
          SKU: moreProductInfo1?.[`SKU${idx + 1}`],
          productId: moreProductInfo1?.[`productId${idx + 1}`],
          condition: moreProductInfo1?.[`condition${idx + 1}`],
          price: moreProductInfo1?.[`price${idx + 1}`],
          quantity: moreProductInfo1?.[`quantity${idx + 1}`],
          colorMap: moreProductInfo1?.[`colorMap${idx + 1}`],
        },
      ]);
    }
  }
});

...
```

`addedVariation` array just provides the number of different items in the object i want to extract the data from. In this case it is 3 objects and here is the data in there:

```
[
  {
    "Color": "violet"
  },
  {
    "Quality": "New"
  },
  {
    "Material": "Cotton"
  }
]
```

I however just get the last object saved and the other two get ignored. Please help

Comment: Do you get this object from api?

Comment: No, from input fields. The input fields are generated using a array.map function (depending on how many attributes the user wants to add to a product) so i cannot have a different array during input, hence the large object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested your code but there's a big problem in your code regarding React state update.

Your `...productsArray` is referred to same value in all of your iterations. [see](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)

You have to use the latest value to set the state,

`setProductsArray(lastState => [...lastState, {attribute: .....}])`

Or better update it once after the loop completed.

```
let normalVariable = productArray;
for() {
  normalVariable = [...normalVariable, {...}]
}
setProductsArray(normalVariable)
```